# How to print a string with quotes in a python 3.x Jupyter lab?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

How do I distinguish between the output of the following in a jupyterlab notebook?

```
  print("hello")
  print("Hello ")
  print("hello   ")
  print("  hello")
  print("  hello ")
```

They all print the same and the spaces are not visible. Basically, I need to see the correct string so I can copy it. This is python 3.x

Comment: It isn't clear what you want here. This is true for any kind of output printing anywhere - you don't see spaces because they are not visible to the human eye. If am in doubt (which is mainly for debugging) I surround things with some delimiter - eg `print("|  hello |")`. Other than that, printing things to copy them and expecting to be able to "see" or otherwise correctly "select" spaces manually is not really something to be relied on.

Comment: Leading spaces are very well visible, as they are shifting the visible word. Trailing ones aren't. But you can "see" them by "selecting" the output lines.

Comment: Are you looking to "print" a set of quotes when you print?  `print("\"  hello \"")`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking. I solved it myself:

```
 for h in ["hello", " hello", "hello  "]:
       print("'%s'"%h)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Not really clear how it is related to your own question. So you have added visible delimiters as @topsail suggested, but it is not really what you asked about.

Comment: Alternatively, substitute the last line with `display(h)` or `print(f"'{h}'")` for Jupyter or easier modern Python, respectively.